# Visual studio starts compiling when we open a solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Please help me in understanding why visual studio starts compiling a project when we open it? Is there a way to suppress this?

Comment: Does it compiles for all the projects or any specific type of project , like "Console Application" etc.

Comment: I have a solution which has a library project, it start compilation when i open it. Or rather i should ask what all happens when i open a solution in visual studio?

Comment: What is the type of that library project ?

Comment: Hmm, The only reason i know why a project build on load is because the project template used to create the project should have defined <BuildOnLoad>true</BuildOnLoad>. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247199(v=vs.140).aspx. But this is only for the first time the project is created. But if it's building whenever you open it it's probably because you have any extension installed that does that. A plain installation of visual studio will not build projects on load. Which version of visual studio are you using